# retrive data from sqlite

Tags: android

What I am trying to achieve is retrieve records from SQLite database which are in the range of 3 days before current date and 3 days after current date including current date.

how to do this,please suggest some example to try out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the column in which you store the date should be an long type. This column will store the milliseconds from epoch for the date.

Now for Query

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // This will give you the current time.
    // Removing the timestamp from current time to point to todays date
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -3); // Will subtract 3 days from today.
    Date beforeThreeDays = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6); // Will be your 3 days after today
    Date afterThreeDays = calendar.getTime();

    db.query("Table", null, "YOUR_DATE_COLUMN >= ? AND YOUR_DATE_COLUMN <= ?", new String[] { beforeThreeDays.getTime() + "", afterThreeDays.getTime() + "" }, null, null, null);
```

Comment: thank you @vivek i will try this, & will let you know about this

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
From TABLE_NAME
WHERE  DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), COLUMN_TABLE) <= 3
```

Comment: Cursor c = sdb
    .rawQuery(
      "select Reminder_Id ,Reminder_Type,Reminder_Date,Reminder_Time,Reminder_Alert  from " i m try this for current date how to implement in this
        + Reminder_Main
        + " where "
        + Car_ID
        + " = ? AND  " + Reminder_Date + " = ? ",
      new String[] { summaryid, currentdate1 });